# Android: Background Squeezes on entering the input text box when the keyboard is pulled up

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is the XML code:
I have a scroll pane and at the bottom I have a static linear layout which consists of a search box and a button. When I click on the search box the background contracts/ squeezes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"                               android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"       android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <Button android:id="@+id/American" android:layout_width="130dp"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp" android:layout_marginRight="110dp"     android:text="American" android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"     android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Austrailian" android:layout_width="130dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Austrailian" android:layout_below="@id/American"   android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" android:background="@drawable/mybutton"     android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp" /> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Burmese" android:layout_width="130dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Burmese" android:layout_below="@id/Austrailian"    android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Chinese" android:layout_width="130dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"       android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Chinese" android:layout_below="@id/Burmese"    android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/French" android:layout_width="130dp"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="French" android:layout_below="@id/Chinese" android:gravity="center"    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:textColor="#45125d"     android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Greek" android:layout_width="130dp"    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Greek" android:layout_below="@id/French" android:gravity="center"  android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:textColor="#45125d"     android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Indian" android:layout_width="130dp"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Indian" android:layout_below="@id/Greek" android:gravity="center"  android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:textColor="#45125d"     android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Italian" android:layout_width="130dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Italian" android:layout_below="@id/Indian" android:gravity="center"    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton" android:textColor="#45125d"     android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Japanese" android:layout_width="130dp"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Japanese" android:layout_below="@id/Italian"   android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Lebanese" android:layout_width="130dp"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Lebanese" android:layout_below="@id/Japanese"  android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Mexican" android:layout_width="130dp"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Mexican" android:layout_below="@id/Lebanese"   android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/Pakistani" android:layout_width="130dp"    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="05dp" android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"   android:layout_marginRight="110dp" android:text="Pakistani" android:layout_below="@id/Mexican"  android:gravity="center" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"  android:background="@drawable/mybutton"    android:textColor="#45125d" android:textSize="20dp"/> 




    </LinearLayout>   
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="-70dip" android:gravity="bottom"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/Searchbox" 
        android:width="100dp" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="25dp" 
        android:hint="   Search"  
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/search"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Search" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

        android:background="@drawable/searchbutton"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:weight=1 in the scroll view or 2nd linearlayout.

Comment: Tried but it says no resource identifier found for the attribute weight in package android?

Comment: if you use android:weight, then you have use to set android:weight property to 0dp.